# Error al tratar de ejecutar mi archivo localmente con XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

modifique el archivo .env de mi proyecto y ya no puedo abrilo localmente y sinceramente no se que estoy haciendo mal si la llamada o algun error de codigo.
Cuando abro el localhost me larga el error *HTTP ERROR 500*, pero no se si sea ya directamente una configuracion de XAMPP por que en el archivo .htaccess estoy usando *RewriteEngine on* para que habilite el motor *mod_rewrite* para este directorio.
*Aca dejo el codigo de .htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Y aca dejo el archivo de .env para que lo revisen

```
APP_NAME="Ecommerce"
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_ENV=production

APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_KEY=base64:ahimIiG674yV4DkPWx6f7t9dkMmTFK2S+0lCPglpVfs=
LOG_CHANNEL=daily

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379


DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="ecommerce"
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD=""
DB_STRICT=false

ADMIN_DIR=admin
```

Comment: Primero revisa los logs de apache y php.

Comment: Un dato importante que no va a solucionar el error justo ahora, pero te puede servir muchísimo en el futuro: **_Siempre haz un backup de los archivos antes de modificarlos_**